# Why does my switch work when it has single quotes?

Tags: c#

So disclaimer, I am pretty new to C# and trying to learn the finer intricacies. I have a classwork assignment that I coded and it works, but I'm not sure why it works, and want to understand it.

Here is the code, Its not the full code, i just cut out the relevant parts:

```
    int studentType = 0;
    switch (studentType)
    {
        case 1:
            studentType = '1';
            WriteLine("What is your GPA?");
            gpa = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
            break;

        case 2:
            studentType = '2';
            WriteLine("What is the title of your thesis?");
            thesis = ReadLine();
            break;

        case 3:
            studentType = '3';
            WriteLine("What is the title of your dissertation?");
            dissertation = ReadLine();
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        default:
            WriteLine("Invalid option input.");
            break;
    }//Switch for student Type
```

As noted, the case command works perfectly fine like this. What I accidently did was initially put case 'x': and that ended up not working, so i deleted all the single quotes.

Here is the 2nd part, and why I am confused:

```
    switch (studentType)
    {
        case '1':
        case '4':
            WriteLine($"GPA: {gpa:f2}");
            break;

        case '3':
            WriteLine($"Dissertation title: {dissertation}");
            break;

        case '2':
            WriteLine($"Thesis title: {thesis}");
            break;
    }//end of studentType switch
```

So originally I tried writing the case without the single quotes, but every time I ran 1, GPA never populated, so I tried to put in the single quotes, and it works, but I'm not sure why.

Since studentType is an integer, it would make sense for the first switch to be without single quotes, but how is the switch requiring single quotes?

I guess I can submit it as is as long as it works correctly, but I mainly want to understand whats going on.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DarkBee: It really doesn't - it's asking why a switch statement works when the OP doesn't expect it to.

Comment: Because you're mingling use of quotes and non-use of quotes, you're experiencing some implicit conversions between `char` and `int`. So why one works and the other doesn't probably relates both to your trying to *compare* a value **and** to how the value was initially set. But you're only showing us the comparison code.

Comment: Research variable declaration in c# and the types string, char & int.  Also, when it's 'not working' read and understand the errors being thrown by the compiler - they'll help massively when trying to understand what is wrong with your program.

Comment: @PhilCooper: There wouldn't be any compile-time errors, just unexpected results.

Comment: @JonSkeet I naively didn't anticipate that - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, and a constant `char` expression can be used as a constant `int` expression, which is what you've got. The value of the `int` is the UTF-16 code unit associated with the `char`.

Here's another example of that:

```
const int X = 'x';
```

That's also why your assignment statements worked:

```
studentType = '1';
```

So this:

```
int value = ...;
switch (value)
{
    case '1':
        // ...
        break;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
int value = ...;
switch (value)
{
    case 49:
        // ...
        break;
}
```

... because 49 is the UTF-16 code point associated with the character '1'.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: 
In the first switch, I incorrectly called studentType 1, 2, 3? The reason I did that was an earlier part of the code: 

        WriteLine("1. Undergraduate");
        WriteLine("2. Graduate");
        WriteLine("3. PHD");
        WriteLine("4. Non-degree certificate");
I was thinking I had to put the options inside the switch statement. But instead what that is actually doing is making studentType into a char because of the = '1'? 

So I can remove all the studentType = 'x', then remove the ' ' from the 2nd switch. Am I correct?

Comment: @Synik: Fundamentally, you ought to decide whether you want `studentType` to be an integer with values 1, 2, 3 or a char with values '1', '2', '3'... or better yet, an enum with values Undergraduate, Graduate, PhD. I'd go with the enum version myself, performing the conversion from the user input as early as possible.

Comment: Based off my assignment criteria, 'studentType' needs to be an integer. I'm not sure what enum means yet, but when I get to my home PC, I'll take out the 'studentType = '1'', ect, and remove the single quotes from the 2nd switch and test it that way. For clarification, my full noob code is [here](https://pastebin.com/3q2Y58UQ)

Comment: Just wanted to say I got it working fine after removing the studentType = 'x' values, then removing the single quotes from the 2nd switch. I understand now that the studentType inside the first case was unneeded. Thank you, sir!